# What's this romantic comedy about a housemaid pretending to be the owner?

Tags: comedy, identify-this-movie

Need help finding the name of the following movie:

There was a guy who lived in an apartment in a big city (likely New York City), and there was a woman who posed as his housesitter/keeper while he went away for a (business?) trip. I can't remember if he actually hired her or if she just pretended to be his maid through some situational comedic hijinks, but I know they never actually met before she began acting as a maid, and at some point (probably because the guy's trip was cut short), they bumped into each other somehow, and he didn't reveal himself as the true owner of the apartment. And I believe she let the guy assume that she was the true owner of the apartment, and she even invites the guy into "her" (actually his) place.

They began to have a little romantic relationship, All the while, the guy is staying at his friend's apartment until he can sort things out with his lady interest/maid and move back in. At some point, the guy even invites the lady back to "his" (actually his friend's) place for wine.

Anyway, towards the end of the movie, I think the woman found out that the guy who she had been seeing was really the owner of the apartment all along - I think it was through some interaction she had with the local dry cleaner. One of the final scenes had the woman (and her best friend, who had been aware of the caper the whole time) throwing a party in the apartment with a bunch of women either in costume or very skimpy clothing (can't remember), and I think the cops shut it down because they thought it was a disturbance of the peace or something.

I think that's a good description. Let me know if you can help me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: That Funny Feeling (1965) - Movie Poster]

[**That Funny Feeling** (1965)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059794/)

> **Joan Howell, a young and pretty maid-for-hire**, meets and begins **dating wealthy New York City businessman Tom Milford**.

[image: That Funny Feeling (1965) - Pic 01]

> Embarrassed about bringing him back to her tiny apartment that she
>   shares with her roommate Audrey, **Joan brings Tom over to a fancy
>   apartment that she cleans** on a daily basis **not knowing that it's
>   his place**.

[image: That Funny Feeling (1965) - Pic 02]

> **Tom plays along with the charade** despite not knowing who Joan really is, while **she tries to tidy up Tom's place not knowing who he
>   really is**.

And like you described, here's how it ends:

> To see how far Joan is prepared to go, Tom moves in with his pal
>   Harvey and goes along with it. As soon as Joan becomes aware of the
>   truth, however, **she gets even by throwing a party** with girls
>   pretending to be prostitutes, whereupon **the party is promptly raided
>   by the cops.**

Watch it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTGkF1uvk2o) to confirm.

<sup>*~ Text from [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059794/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_Funny_Feeling); Poster from [movieposter.com](http://www.movieposter.com/poster/MPW-18937/That_Funny_Feeling.html); Screenshots from [Fedoras and High Heels](http://fedorasandhighheels.blogspot.com/2011/03/that-funny-feeling-1965.html)*</sup>

Comment: Excelente! Did you just know this off the top of your head or did you use the right search keywords? I looked for the name of this a while back, but I never found the magical combination of search terms.

Comment: Glad to pitch in! And to answer your question, I rarely get to track down movies I've seen :-)